# regex for numeric range 900 to 864000

Tags: regex

Can u all please help me out to get the regex for the range 900 to 864000
thank you

Comment: Regex is _overkill_ here. Use Comparison `if (num >= 900 && num <= 86400)`

Comment: hey tushar thanks for reply , but the java code i use is generic code which works for different numeric ranges,which accepts regex for the range validation , among those  900 to 864000 is one of the range

Answer (score 1):

This platform is for helping with your regex, not writing your code. You probably need to split this problem into several subsections and combine  them with `|` pipes in an [anchored](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

1. `900`-`999`
       to match `9` followed by two [digits](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html):  `9\d\d`
2. `1000`-`99999`
    any four or five digits:                 `\d{4,5}`
3. `100000`-`799999`
    `1-7` followed by any 5 digits: `[1-7]\d{5}`
4. `800000`-`859999`
    eight followed by zero to five and any 4 digits: `8[0-5]\d{4}`
5. `860000`-`863999`
   eight followed by six followed by zero to 3 and any 3 digits:
   *Get coffee or better tea an try yourself!*
6. `864000`

An inital [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!0)` to disallow leading zeroes if desired .

<sup>[unveil secret solution](https://regex101.com/r/eV6iR8/1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: You are welcome @SuneilNarasimhamurthy!